# How to determine the slope of the tangent to the curve at $x=a$

Tags: calculus

Considering the function $y=-x^2-3x+4$, how do I determine the slope of the tangent to the curve at $x=a$?

I think it has something to do with derivatives but I'm not quite sure. Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of your function is:

${d y \over d x} = -2 x - 3$.

Then just plug in $x = a$ to get the slope $m$.

Then you know the equation of the tangent is $y = m x + b$.  Since you know your tangent goes through the point $(a, y(a))$, you can solve for $b$.